# Chrome Extension : "chrome.runtime.sendMessage" Is Not Working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

**I am currently working on a Chrome Extension that will close my currently opened tab if it finds a specific word in the HTML of the page.**

My content.js script will find the forbidden word in the HTML of my opened tab (if it has it) and then run this code: `chrome.runtime.sendMessage({request: "closeTab" })`

My background.js script should receive this message with: `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function closeTab(request, sender, sendResponse) {if (request == "closeTab") {//code});`

All the code in my content.js script is functioning correctly and is sending that message. Despite that, the background.js will not do anything. I would really appreciate it if somebody could tell me why.

*Edit: I no longer have the error message that had shown up previously. But the code in the background.js file is still not running.

*Edit: To help I took a screenshot of the console and what it looked like. [Screenshot of Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0okC.png)

*Just in case you need it, I'll leave the code:*

**content.js**

```js
// content.js
const forbiddenText = "cheese";

//Program that looks for forbidden text
function checkForForbiddenText() {
  console.log("Checking for Forbidden Text.....");
  const bodyText = document.body.innerText;
  if (bodyText.includes(forbiddenText)) {
    console.log("Forbidden text found! Closing the tab...");
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage("closeTab")};
    console.log(chrome.runtime.sendMessage("closeTab"));
  }


// Run the checkForForbiddenText function when the page is fully loaded
window.addEventListener("load", checkForForbiddenText);
```

```js
// background.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function closeTab(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.from === "closeTab") {
      // Close the current tab
      console.log("Background Running.....");
      chrome.tabs.remove(sender.tab.id)
          console.log("Tab closed");
        
    }
  });
  
  chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    // Add any other logic you need for tab updates
    console.log("Tab updated:", changeInfo);
  });
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
"manifest_version": 3,
"name": "Test Blocker",
"version": "1",
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab"
],
"background": {
     "service_worker": "background.js"
},
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
    
}
```

]
}

Comment: 1) Remove chrome.tabs.getCurrent, 2) Use chrome.tabs.remove(sender.tab.id), 3) Note that in Chrome you can close the tab using window.close() in the content script.

Comment: I have done all that you suggested. I removed chrome.tabs.getcurrent and it still doesn't work. And using window.close() unfortunately doesn't work because scripts can't close the tab that way unless the were the one who opened them.

Comment: But I did do some debugging and now I know that the problem for sure involves the chrome.runtime.onMessage() and not the code inside of it.

Comment: 1) Replace `request` with `from` in sendMessage. 2) window.close() works in a content script in Chrome regardless of who opened the tab.

Comment: I have replaced  `request` with `from`, as you suggested, but now it gives me an error saying I have an anonymous function on line 6 of background.js. || I also tried putting in the window.close() in my content script and an error tells me: Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them.

Comment: Show the exact text of the error and show your new code in background.js.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the code and left an image of the error.

Comment: I edited my post to include the exact code and a picture of the exact problem.

Comment: 1) You've simplified the `if` check in onMessage, but you didn't simplify sendMessage. Replace `{from: "closeTab" }` with `"closeTab"`. Also use devtools to interactively set breakpoints and inspect what's being sent and what's being received. 2) You didn't show me your new onMessage entirely so I don't know what's  wrong there. Did you correctly use sender.tab.id as I suggested?

Comment: Ok, I fixed what you told me to fix (sorry it took 13  hours btw). The content.js .sendMessage is simplified and that previous error is no longer showing up. But my previous problem is still going on. I edited my post with all of my current code too.

Comment: I also removed `chrome.tabs.getCurrent` and am also using `chrome.tabs.remove(sender.tab.id)` in my code just like you suggested.

Comment: Remove `.from` in background.js. Make sure you use devtools to inspect what you send and what you receive.

Comment: The tabs close now! But now the program closes every tab I open.

Comment: Actually, I don't think it closes every tab.

Comment: Anyway, the problem this post was created is fixed soo, so Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
Change:
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage("closeTab")};
to:
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action:"closeTab"});

Change:
  if (request.from === "closeTab") {
to:
  if (request.action == "closeTab") {
```

Also check your closing braces in content.js ...